# Is it possible to export MySQL database by a JButton action event?

Tags: java, mysql

I want to export my MySQL database from my Java Application so that I can replicate it to somewhere else to keep it safe.

Is it possible to do so? Please suggest other ways (if possible) to keep the database safe.

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: Very soon my reputation will drop to zero. :( Everyone's downvoting..
???

Answer (score 0):

try below code or this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217532/exporting-database-through-my-java-code)

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
{
private String m_MySqlPath=""; 
ResultSet res=null;
res = DBHandler.getInstance().executeQuery("select @@basedir",null);

      while(res.next())
      {
          m_MySqlPath=res.getString(1) ;
      }



      m_MySqlPath = m_MySqlPath.replace("\\Data\\", "\\bin\\");

if (exportDB.isSelected()
{    
try {

      String executeCmd = m_MySqlPath + "\\mysqldump -u " + DB_USER
      +" -p" + DB_PASSWORD + " " + DB_NAME + " -r " + "\""+FilePath + "\\"
      + FileName+"\"";

    Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd, null);

    BufferedReader r=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(runtimeProcess.getInputStream()));
    String s;
    while((s=r.readLine())!=null)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    return true;

}
catch (final Exception ex) {
    ex.printstackTrace();
    return false;
}
}
```